# What could you do in order to figure out if that charge is positive or negative?

Tags: electrostatics

If you take clothes directly out of the dryer, they sometimes have built up an electric charge. How could you figure out, if that charge is positive or negative?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. I think an easy way could be...

Take a glass and a cloth, and rub the cloth against the glass. That should rip out electrons from the glass, so the glass becomes positively charged.

Now take the glass near the dryer. If it does nothing, it means you're putting possitive charages against other possitive charges. However, if there is a spark, it means that charges are jumping from one to another, so the dryer would be negatively charged.

Let me know if this works, in the comments.